# Is it possible to create a small server side rendering blog type website on AWS free forever tier?

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, next.js, server, server-side-rendering

Is it possible to create a small server side rendering blog type website on AWS free forever tier? If yes, then which services I have to use? (like aws lambda, dynamodb etc.).

Comment: The AWS Free Tier is intended as a means of 'trying' AWS. It is not provided as a way of providing "always free" services.

Answer (score 4):

Go [here](https://aws.amazon.com/free/?all-free-tier.sort-by=item.additionalFields.SortRank&all-free-tier.sort-order=asc&awsf.Free%20Tier%20Types=tier%23always-free&awsf.Free%20Tier%20Categories=*all) and filter the services by "Always Free".

Lambda is the only compute environment that offers an Always Free tier. You could design a system that uses AWS Lambda compute, DynamoDB for storage, and have it served by CloudFront, and as long as you stayed within all the free tier limits and didn't get too many requests per month, and didn't serve much data, then you could probably get away with that being completely free.

There are tons of ways that you could end up getting charged though, like if your total Lambda compute time goes over the limit, or your data transfer out goes over the limit, or your Lambda function's logs go over the limit, etc... It seems like all it would take is for a web crawler to hit your website a bit aggressively and you would go over the limit.

Also note that there are no file storage services with an "Always Free" tier. So it seems like the only files you could serve would be the ones packaged into your Lambda function's deployment artifact.